# Something about the "cidx" of SparseMatrix Class using Octave API in C++

Tags: c++, octave

All,
I have below c++ code to test the sparsematrix class of Octave library,

```
SparseMatrix BB=SparseMatrix(10,10,3);
            BB(2,1)=2;
            BB(4,3)=3;
            BB(1,2)=10;
            long ff1=BB.cidx(0);
            long ff2=BB.cidx(1);
            long ff3=BB.cidx(2);
```

Based on my understanding, the ff1, ff2,ff3 are supposed to be 1, 2, 3, respectively. However, the real values of ff1,ff2 and ff3 I got from above code are 0,0,1.

Is this result correct? Is there anyone that can explain the meaning of "cidx" explicitly for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to read this: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0604006 It describes Sparse Matrix Implementation details in Octave